# Why is this not undefined?

Tags: javascript, this

I have this code:

```js
const employee = {
  name: 'Jen Baker',
  getName: function() {
    return this.name;
  }
};

const getEmployeeName = employee.getName;

console.log(getEmployeeName()); // returns '' (empty string)
```

Why does `getEmployeeName()` return an empty string?  Shouldn't it be `undefined` because it has lost reference to `this.name` in the employee object?  Where did the empty string come from?

Comment: Because there is a [`name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) in `window`

Comment: When the function is called it is given the scope of `window` so `this.name` is equivalent to `window.name` which is an empty string.

Comment: If you put `"use strict";` at the beginning, then `this` will be `undefined`, so you will get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

Comment: Also, you're calling that const as a function which confuses things.

Comment: @AndrewBone — At no point do they have `employee()` in their code.

Comment: @Quentin `getEmployeeName()`

Comment: @AndrewBone — Well, it is a function. So what is confusing about that?

Comment: @Quentin I've commented my code https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/m0p2gs1v/